# How to initialize Admob app id programatically without Manifest

Tags: java, android, server, admob

i am trying to make my Admob ads hosted in a server and my app will import them, so i can change them whenever i want easily. My ads working fine but the only problem is i don't know how to change my APP ID programatically as it must be placed in Manifest `<meta-data />`.
So is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It was possible in previous versions but not now. You can't change it programatically.

Comment: what if i used an old sdk version of admob?